# How to add bootstrap.js in magento2

Tags: magento2, jquery

I m trying to include bootstrap js on my magento2 theme. But the problem is when i include bootstrap js on my theme. That time console is giving error that bootstrap require jQuery.

Then how can i do it??? 
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create Module Folder Structure:

```
app / code / [Vendor] / [ModuleName]

app / code / [Vendor] / [ModuleName] / etc

app / code / [Vendor] / [ModuleName] / view / frontend / layout
```

Create Module Files:

```
app / code / [Vendor] / [ModuleName] / registration.php

app / code / [Vendor] / [ModuleName] / etc / module.xml

app / code / [Vendor] / [ModuleName] / view / frontend / requirejs-config.js

app / code / [Vendor] / [ModuleName] / view / frontend / layout / default.xml

app / code / [Vendor] / [ModuleName] / view / frontend / layout / default_head_blocks.xml
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[Vendor]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Vendor]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "jquery.bootstrap": "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="head">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Head\Script" name="requirejs" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <!-- RequireJs library enabled -->
                <argument name="file" xsi:type="string">requirejs/require.js</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <!-- Special block with necessary config is added on the page -->
        <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config" after="requirejs"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

**default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" src_type="url"/>
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Enable Module (SSH to magento root):

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content [Vendor]_[ModuleName]

php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Deploy static resources (SSH to magento root):

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**RequireJS will not load any javascript module source file until someone uses that javascript module as a dependency.** per [Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_and_requirejs)

(example usage) in CMS Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery', 'jquery.bootstrap'], function (jQuery, jQueryBootstrap) {
        jQuery('.carousel').carousel();
    });
</script>
```

**Related:** [*Adding CSS to a CMS page using Layout Update XML*](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/107521/5880)

Comment: Thanks for this :) A very clear guide. Though I find it weird to see the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` value in `default.xml`. It looks to me this goes against all the modularity in Magento, to define a path like that. But I see it all over the web, so it must be the way things work.

Comment: Indeed the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` is outdated, or even wrong. Currently it should be `urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd` which makes it flexible.

Comment: I don't think the addition of `default.xml` is actually needed. Magento 2 already loads RequireJS everywhere on all pages, so there is no need to explicitely add RequireJS yourself.

Comment: Upped this post anyway, because it is awesome.

Answer (score 7):

**To add bootstrap JS file, I followed the following steps on Magento 2.2.4.**

**Step 1:** Place the JS file in the following location.

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{Themename}/Magento_Theme/web/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
```

**Step 2:** Add the following scripts in this file `app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{Themename}/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js`.

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    paths: {
            'bootstrap':'Magento_Theme/js/bootstrap.bundle.min',
    } ,
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

**Step 3:** Add the following scripts in the template files or your custom JS files (without `script` tag).

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'bootstrap'], function($){ 
       // core js, jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap codes go here
    });
</script>
```

**Step 4:** Go to the Magento root folder and run the command below.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```