# Best Way to Add JS file in Magento 2 Theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, javascript

I have created a custom theme. I have to use bootstrap in my theme. So I am adding the JS file as follows :

In theme directory /Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js file.

```
var config = {
 paths:{
"jquery.bootstrap":"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min"
},
shim:{
'jquery.bootstrap':{
    'deps':['jquery']
}
}
};
```

But it's not working.

I have tried with this in default_head_blocks.xml. JS file in theme/web/js directory

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```

But getting error Mismatched anonymous define() module

Comment: Check : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107763/how-to-add-bootstrap-js-in-magento2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add bootstrap.js in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107763/how-to-add-bootstrap-js-in-magento2)

Comment: i have to add in theme not in module. it should be apply global not have to use dependency for bootstrap.

Comment: If I am right ,  i think you are asking for adding js by cdn

Comment: Yes i am adding by CDN.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to add `JS` is with **requirejs**.

To add a js in **theme** via `Requirejs`:

Supposing that your js file is: `myfile.js`

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/myfile'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/myfile.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert('hello myscript');
           //put all your myfile js code here
       }
});
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/{yourfile}.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

**Info:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove add JS in layout.

You already declared dependencies with `requireJS`.

Than use in PHTML as :

```
require(['bootstrap'], function(bootstrap) {
  ... Your code
 });
```

It should work.