# Magento2: How to add separate css file on each cms page?

Tags: magento2, css, xml, cms, page

Is it possible to add individual CSS file on each cms page? Upon researching, I can do it by adding code on Layout update XML.

Unfortunately, it isn't working. Here's my code:

```
<head>
  <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/styles.css"/>
</head>
```

[image]

Comment: Shall i know what is the scenario you need?

Comment: i want to add css file on a specific cms page, in magento 1 here is the code
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addCss">
      <stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet>
   </action>
</reference>

i'm not sure on magento 2

Comment: Which magento 2 version you are using currently? Using custom module to set different css for different  CMS page is working for me in magento 2.3.3 using Layout Update XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/mycustom.css" after="-" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on < version `2.1.9` there was apparently a bug to prevent this from working, I've never tried it but you can read about it here - [Adding CSS to a CMS page using Layout Update XML](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107482/adding-css-to-a-cms-page-using-layout-update-xml)